# Fast connection to Google Services ( in order to receive push notifications)

Tags: java, android, push-notification, connection

I'm facing an issue on my phone under Android Jelly Bean 4.2.1 (but not on my tablet with Android KitKat 4.4.2).

What I have is an **instant push notifications** system which works perfectly, as long as my phone is connected to **Google Services** (**blue icon** in the notification bar on Jelly Bean). I'm working with Parse.

The problem is that it takes about 2 minutes to get a connection and that is way too long.

I've seen a lot of threads about the Heartbeat rate and tried to add those lines in my code:

> context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.GTALK_HEARTBEAT"));
>                  context.sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT"));

but it did nothing and I don't think that it is really my problem here.

In addition, I found by dialing ***#*#426#*#*** that it was possible to get a connection in less than 5 seconds by clicking the "Connect" button in the Google Play Services monitor.

**My question is:** How can I have a fast connection with Google Services (blue icon) in order to receive instant push notifications and is this still a problem on Android KitKat and Lollipop?

I Hope you will be able to help me.

Comment: what blue icon are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about those icons on the notification bar

Comment: May be that yours are grey/green? or they can also be orange/white (in your quick settings)